# Tokenize or Split String Into Text & Html Tag Items

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am looking for the most efficient way to accept a string and token ize it into an array separating out any HTML tag groups.

```
Example Input (String): 
    "I can format my text so that <strong>This is bold</strong> and this is not."

Desired Output (String[] array): 
    "I can format my text so that",
    "<strong>",
    "This is bold",
    "</strong>",
    "and this is not."

Alternate Output Just As Good(String[] array): 
    "I",
    "can",
    "format",
    "my",
    "text",
    "so",
    "that",
    "<strong>",
    "This",
    "is",
    "bold",
    "</strong>",
    "and",
    "this",
    "is",
    "not."
```

I am unsure as to the best way to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Regex.Split(inputString,"(?<=>)|(?=<)");`

Comment: Use `Regex.Split(s, @"(<[^<]*?>)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Split()` with a set of zero-length assertions to split in places followed by `<` or preceded by `>`:

```
string input = "I can format my text so that <strong>This is bold</strong> and this is not.";
string[] output = Regex.Split(input, "(?=<)|(?<=>)");
```

`(?=pattern)` is known as a look-ahead assertion, ensuring that `pattern` follows.
`(?<=pattern)` is a look-behind assertion, same concept but looking at characters *before* the position